# Optimizing array filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/SqJ2y/

```
var list = [
    { mode: 1, type: 'foo', blah: 1 }, 
    { mode: 3, type: 'foo', blah: 1 }, 
    { mode: 3, type: 'foo', blah: 1 },
    { mode: 1, type: 'bar', blah: 1 }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'bar', blah: 0 },
    { mode: 3, type: 'bar', blah: 1 }
];

var filter = [
    { propertyName: 'mode', value: 1 }, 
    { propertyName: 'type', value: 'foo' },
    { propertyName: 'blah', value: 1 }
];

var i = 0;

var result1 = $.grep(list, function(x){
    i++;
    return x.type === 'foo' && x.mode === 1 && x.blah === 1;
});

console.log(result1, 'iterations:', i); // 6 iterations

var j = 0;

var result2 = list;

$.each(filter, function(k, filter){
    result2 = $.grep(result2, function(listItem) {
        j++;
        return listItem[filter.propertyName] === filter.value;
    });
});

console.log(result2, 'iterations:', j); // 9 iterations
```

I would like to optimize my filter method that gives `result2` above.

As you can see in `result1`, the same result can be acheived with less iterations. It might not look like much in my example, but have large lists where performance is an issue.

My question: Is there any way to optimize the filtering for `result2` so that it works as the `result1` filtering?

Comment: if you are ready to use `eval` probably you can create the filter callback dynamically

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, I know. Forgot to mention that I'm not a big fan of eval(). So I would like to avoid it if possible. Thanks though

Comment: me too... that is why I asked it as a clarification

Comment: I think that's a http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: @steo I had a thought about adding it there. Is there any way to move it?

Comment: I think that moderators will

Comment: @Johann: Just flag it as off-topic, that should be sufficient. Don't forget to mention CodeReview as correct SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question: Is there any way to optimize the filtering for result2 so that it works as the result1 filtering?

Yes. `grep` is building a new array for each filter, and it would be better to do that only once. With the native [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) methods:

```
var result3 = list.filter(function(listItem) {
    return filter.every(function(test) {
        return listItem[test.propertyName] === test.value;
    });
});
```

Plain loops would be faster probably. With jQuery's iteration, which doesn't have an `every` equivalent, you'd use one anyway:

```
var result3 = $.grep(list, function(listItem) {
    for (var i=0, l=filter.length; i<l; i++)
        if (listItem[filter[i].propertyName] !== filter[i].value)
            return false;
    return true;
});
```

Of course that would still need to iterate over the `filter`s every time, you don't really get around that (unless you compile a `new Function`). But you can furhter optimize the `filter` array by putting those properties that will filter out the most items in the front.

EDIT: Here's an example with a compiled function:

```
var result4 = list.filter(new Function("listItem",
    "return "+filter.map(function(test) {
         return "listItem."+test.propertyName+"==="+JSON.stringify(test.value);
// make sure that        ^ these are valid      ^  these are primitive
//                         identifiers             value only
    }).join(" && ")+";"
));
```

Yet its performance needs to be thoroughly tested, as evaling the function body can introduce a huge overhead especially in older JS engines. It might be faster for thousands of filtered rows though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Regarding "unless you compile a new Function": Is it worth looking in to for this scenario? Do you have an example?

Comment: Do you really have so many items in your `list` that the nested loops don't cope with that? I don't think the function creation will have a huge performance gain. To make an example I'd need to know whether the `filter` values can be complex objects or only primitive values.

Comment: There are about 100 filter rows with ~10 columns that are filtered at most. IE7 is the only browser that I'm noticing some performance issues. To answer the latter; filter values are only primitive (`Number` to be precise).

Comment: 100 filtered list items should definitely not be a performance issue, not even in IE7. Are you sure the filtering part is the slow thing? Usually it's the DOM.

Comment: I see. Looks like `eval` is used internally for the last solution, right? Thanks for a descriptive answer, as usual.

Comment: Not exaclty, `eval` is broader ("more hacky") than the `Function` constructor. But both need to call the parser, that's true.

Comment: I missed your question. I'm iterating over it up to 10 times (the columns that I mentioned above). Even though the list gets smaller by each iteration, I'm still noticing that the UI thread freezes for a short moment (not getting the popup warning about it, but I prefer to be on the safe side). But in case I get the warning I could just add a short timeout for each "column" to give the thread some breathing space. Thanks again for your input. I always learn something new from your answers!

Answer (score 2):

you can build a matching object first, and re-use it to avoid the loop-de-loop:

```
var ob={};
filter.map(function(a,b){
  ob[a.propertyName]=a.value;
})

result2 =  $.grep(list, function(x){
   j++;
   return x.type === ob.tpye && x.mode === ob.mode && x.blah === ob.blah;
});


/* which has the console showing (and yes, they are the same two objects in both results): 
[Object] "iterations:" 6 
[Object] "iterations:" 6   */
```

full:  http://jsfiddle.net/SqJ2y/2/

Comment: Thanks, but don't forget that `map()` is doing internal loops as well. You should add `j++;` to the map callback, which will result in the same amount of iterations as before.

Comment: @dandavis: I thought the OP's point was that the `propertyName`s (`type`, `mode`, `blah`) are not known before?

Comment: @Johan: yes, but the small loop to build the match object happens very quickly, and saves enough time from the main loop that it more than pays for itself; way better than any sort of nest loop solution. not all iterations are created equal...

Comment: @Bergi: yeah, but one can adapt the object builder to build ob on-the-fly and still enjoy the non-nested perf of my solution, since it separates out the two expensive operations instead of stacking them.

Answer (score 0):

You may combine both previous answers by @dandavis and @Bergi:

```
var filtered = list.filter(function(item) {
  return filter.every(function(f) {
    return f.value === item[f.propertyName];
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, and how would you make this dynamic?

Comment: Yeap, sorry, I didn't get that.